# Bind Data Sets where one has extra column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I am getting the extra column that i wanted but the problem is its getting the data 2 times which ended up showing same data 2 times.[Screen shots of pages[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwOEm.png)

Comment: DataTable dt = dsGenerateReports.Tables[0];
                    GrdVwReport.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                    GrdVwReport.DataSource = dt;
                 

                    GrdVwReport.DataBind();
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add column to "dt" by using : "dt.coulmns.add("NewColumn");" , then the column will show in the grid that if you have set the "asp:grid" attribute AutoGenerateColumns="true" .

If this doesn't solve the problem,
Can you till me what do you mean in "add a column to a Gridview Dynamically" ?

Comment: Thanks it helped, However I never wanted all the columns in the Gridview so I believe i need to hide them all too.

Answer (score 0):

Please use AutoGenerateColumns = True for Gridview and bind after that.

Regards
Abdul